# Liftweb works in Object but not in Class

Tags: json, scala, lift-json

This code works:

```
import net.liftweb.json.{DefaultFormats, parse}

object JsonTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Brings in default date formats etc.
    case class RawObject(filters: List[ChunkObject])
    case class ChunkObject(name: String)

    val json = parse("""{"filters": []}""").extract[RawObject]
    println(json)
  }
}
```

It prints :

```
RawObject(List())
```

This same code within a class does not:

```
import net.liftweb.json.{DefaultFormats, parse}

class JsonTest2 {
  def fct(): Unit = {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats // Brings in default date formats etc.
    case class RawObject(filters: List[ChunkObject])
    case class ChunkObject(name: String)

    val json = parse("""{"filters": []}""").extract[RawObject]
    println(json)
  }
}

object JsonTest2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jt = new JsonTest2
    jt.fct()
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.liftweb.json.MappingException: Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor
args=List()
arg types=scala.collection.immutable.Nil$
constructor=public JsonTest2$RawObject$1(JsonTest2,scala.collection.immutable.List)
    at net.liftweb.json.Meta$.fail(Meta.scala:227)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.instantiate$1(Extraction.scala:274)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.newInstance$1(Extraction.scala:308)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.build$1(Extraction.scala:379)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract0(Extraction.scala:444)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract0(Extraction.scala:206)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:43)
    at net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JValue.extract(JsonAST.scala:703)
    at JsonTest2.fct(JsonTest2.scala:9)
    at JsonTest2$.main(JsonTest2.scala:17)
    at JsonTest2.main(JsonTest2.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.instantiate$1(Extraction.scala:265)
    ... 9 more
```

What did I miss?

PS: with a simple json (only a field with a string value so without a List inside) it works in both Object and Class

EDIT: I think it is related to the case class definition inside the function but i do not understand why.

Comment: Does it work if you move those nested classes out of `JsonTest2`? If so, you are right that the problem is the nested type. In Scala there is a different nested type for each *instance* of `JsonTest2` and that may be confusing things.

Comment: Yes I tested my "EDIT" and now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of the error messages it seems that the constructor for `RawObject` takes an additional argument that liftweb is not expecting:

> constructor=public
> JsonTest2$RawObject$1(JsonTest2,scala.collection.immutable.List)

`RawObject` is a nested type, and in Scala nested types are unique for each instance of the containing object. So `RawObject` inside one instance of `JsonTest2` is not the same type as `RawObject` inside a different instance of `JsonTest2`.

I am guessing that Scala places the instance of the containing type (`JsonTest2`) in the nested type (`RawObject`) so that it can determine the type at runtime. Hence that `JsonTest2` argument to the constructor for `RawObject`.

So moving `RawObject` and `ChunkObject` out of the `JsonTest2` class will fix the problem. These can be placed in the companion object to keep things neat.